# "[Error] pointer value used where a floating point value was expected" How to solve this error?

Tags: c++, c

my code is Below 
I want convert Fahrenheit to degree Celsius in the following code but i am getting error does anybody know how to tackle with this error ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int frnhet[]={0,20,40,60,80,100,120,140,160,180,200,220,240,260,280,300};
    double celcius;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<16;i++)
        {
      celcius = ((float)(5/9) + (float)(frnhet-32));
        printf("celcius = %f",celcius);
       }
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: ***but i am getting error*** what error?

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
what error you are getting?

Comment: `frnhet-32` is UB but yields a pointer.

Comment: `celcius = (frnhet[i] - 32)*5.0/9.0;`

Comment: This _exact_ newbie bug (`5/9` in a Fahrenheit to Celsius calculator) has been written millions of times before and therefore this exact question has been asked hundreds of times before on SO. Please do some research before asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is here:

```
celcius = ((float)(5/9) + (float)(frnhet-32));
```

it must be `frnhet[i]` since **frnhet** is an array

```
celcius = ((float)(5 / 9) + (float)(frnhet[i] - 32));
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed index to frnhet in code. Please refer following code -

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        int frnhet[]={0,20,40,60,80,100,120,140,160,180,200,220,240,260,280,300};
        double celcius;
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<16;i++)
            {
          celcius = ((float)(5/9) + (float)(frnhet[i]-32));
            printf("celcius = %f",celcius);
           }
         return 0;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

`frnhet` is an array and in the expression `frnhet-32` it will convert to pointer to its first element. Change `frnhet-32` to `frnhet[i]-32`.

```
celcius = (5.0/9 + frnhet[i]-32);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change line

```
celcius = ((float)(5/9) + (float)(frnhet-32));
```

To

```
celcius = ((float)(5/9) + (float)(frnhet[i]-32));
```

you missed the index to access `frnht` array

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int frnhet[]={0,20,40,60,80,100,120,140,160,180,200,220,240,260,280,300};
    double celcius;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<16;i++)
        {
      celcius = ((float)(5/9) + (float)(frnhet[i]-32));
        printf("celcius = %f",celcius);
       }
     return 0;
 }
```

In `celcius = ((float)(5/9) + (float)(frnhet-32));` you are passing pointer where it is excepting float value. for passing value use `celcius = ((float)(5/9) + (float)(frnhet[i]-32));`